# Issue with searching for strings in text in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting, backup

I am building a script to monitor backups with Ahsay in PowerShell and have run into an issue with identifying backup types, it works by checking for certain keywords in the first few lines of the log file, and I want to have it so that if it contains the word "File List" but also contains the word "Database" it is not logged as a Files type backup - code below (the variable $LogType contains the text that is being searched):

```
get-childitem -Exclude *Scheduler*, *SystemTray*, *Archived*,*System*| select -last 1 | Get-Content -totalcount 13 -outvariable LogType
if($LogType -notlike "*Database*" -and $LogType -like "*file list*")
{
...
}
```

This returns as true and executes the if statement when the text it is searching is:

```
[2018/01/14 19:30:06] [info] Start [ Windows Server 2008 R2 (FS1), AhsayOBM 6.27.0.0 ]
[2018/01/14 19:30:10] [info] Using Temporary Directory C:\Users\systemadmin\.temp
[2018/01/14 19:30:10] [info] Start running pre-commands
[2018/01/14 19:30:10] [info] Finished running pre-commands
[2018/01/14 19:30:11] [info] Start creating Shadow Copy Set ...
[2018/01/14 19:30:21] [info] Shadow Copy Set successfully created Database
[2018/01/14 19:30:21] [info] Downloading server file list ...
[2018/01/14 19:36:44] [info] Downloading server file list ... Completed
[2018/01/14 19:36:45] [info] Reading backup source from hard disk
```

...

I am having trouble understanding why this is the case, can anyone help?

Comment: What have you got in `$LogType`? How do you populate it? (Please edit the question and fill in the details, don't answer in comment. Those are hard to read.)

Comment: You should add some info of the content of the variable `$LogType`. In your question you type "File List" and in your script you change it to "file list". Please notice the diferent casing. Maybe use `$LogType.ToUpper() -notlike "*DATABASE*" -and $LogType.ToUpper() -like "*FILE LIST*"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is case of PowerShell being a little too helpful.

1. `Get-Content` outputs an array of strings by default, one string per line.
2. The comparison operators work differently when used with collections, they will evaluate once per item and return each item that matches.  For example

   `(0..10) -eq 5`

   Would return `5`
3. PowerShell interprets quite a few things as `true`, including an array that is not empty.

Basically, both of those conditions are true for at least one line in the file, so the statement is technically true. The easiest way to fix the issue would be to read the file as a single string with the `-Raw` parameter.

```
$LogType = Get-Content $myFile -Raw -TotalCount 13
```

**Edit:** If `-Raw` and `-TotalCount` aren't working together right, you can just use `-TotalCount` and combine manually.

```
$fileContent = Get-Content $myFile -TotalCount 13
$LogType = $fileContent -join [Environment]::NewLine
```

Comment: Sadly -Raw and -TotalCount do not play nicely!
I tried having it output to a file then reading that in as raw but still no luck

Comment: @TomHalverson updated with a second step that manually joins them into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your '-notlike' isn't working but I'm sure it has something to do with the way your String gets evaluated, it might be that it's an array of Strings instead of one complete String(depending on how you populate it). As an interim solution while I try it on my machine or at least as a test could you maybe try nesting 2 if statements? Something like this perhaps:

```
if($LogType -like "*file list*")
{
   if ($LogType -like "*Database*") {
    ...
   } else {
    ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work that way - strange that the -notlike wasn't working though

Comment: I'm glad you got it working though, if you don't mind, please up-vote the answers that were useful to you. Happy scripting!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working properly in the end by using

```
if($LogType -like "*Database*" -eq $False -and $LogType -like "*file list*")
{
...
}
```